In the Jungle of Conductors in Class Field Theory
In context of algebraic number theory, are there some interesting connections between global conductors, conductors of orders of rings of integers of number fields and Artin conductors?
The question is motivated by this answer by Keith Conrad. Part of the linked question (see the "metaquestion part) dealed with when the ring of integers $O_K$ of number field $K/ \Bbb Q$ is generated by single element, ie is of shape $\Bbb Z[r]$ for some $r \in O_K$ ( ie when does the principal generator theorem "descend" to ring of integers).
Usually, the "standard object" measuring how far a subring ("order") $\Bbb Z[r] \subset O_K$ "is away" from beeing actually $O_K$ is measured by conductor ideal of this order.
But as pointed out by Keith Conrad there is also an indirect way to detect when $O_K$ cannot be of the shape $\Bbb Z[r]$: That cannot be the case when the different ideal isn't a principal ideal, see Theorem 4.3 here. That's a sufficient, but not neccessary criterion.
The interesting thing is that this criterion is based on information incoded in the different ideal; an object which (together with discriminant ideal obtained is it's image under norm map) primary only carries information about the ramification behavior, so a "local" information.
So this suggests that the information on ramification behavior - as the different ideal can be regarded as "carrier" of ramification information - isn't unrelated to the feature if $O_K$ has shape $\Bbb Z[r]$ - an information which intrinsically carried by conductor ideals of orders.
Now it is know that the discriminant ideal - obtained as mentioned as norm of different ideal - admits decomposition according to so called Conductor-discriminant formula by product of appropr powers of Artin conductors.
This suggest that there migth exist some connections betweenArtin conductors and conductors of orders.
Last but not least there exist notion of global conductor obtained as product of local conductors, which carries also information about ramification behaviour of considered extension $K/\Bbb Q$.
Now the questions are if there are some closer relations between concepts of global conductors, conductors of orders and Artin conductors beyond just lexical connection in sharing partially same names? Moreover, it should be expected that global conductor and the different ideal should be "nearly the same ideal", because both govern ramification. In which nuances they actually differ?
To extract/ pin down precisely main concerns of the question:
(1) Are there relations between Artin conductors and conductors of orders? Apprear mysterios...
(2) Close connection between discriminant ideal and global conductor appear on other hand plausible as both control directly ramification. In which sense they differ?
Maybe a "starting point" adressing 2nd point: If we come back to the mentioned conductor-discriminant formula: Are the Artin conductors appearing in product somehow related to the global conductor of the extension?

A related post: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2022/definition-and-meaning-of-the-conductor-of-an-elliptic-curve.

@KCd: the analogy with elliptic curve situation where we have on one hand the conductor of the curve governing the ramification and on the other hand the conductors of orders of the endomorphism ring suggests that one should not expect existence of any connection between global conductor of "main object" (ie the elliptic curve or number field) and on other hand the conductors of orders. It just the name, so point (1) with putative connection to conductors of orders above is a dead end.

But what about point (2)? As global conductor and discriminant ideal carry both information about ramification it seems that these are not unrelated? Can one say more about their relation, except that that they have same finite prime divisors (but presumably with different multiplicity)? I mean, invoking the mentioned c-d formula, do the Artin conductors appearing in this product decomposition in certain sense exhaust the the global conductor of the extension? Can this putative connection be made more precise?
